# Access JUnit's resources with ServiceTestCase

Tags: android, service, junit

Does anyone know how to access JUnit's own project `res/` folder compiled `R` instance when extending from [`ServiceTestCase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ServiceTestCase.html)?

The usual way does not work:

```
getInstrumentation().getContext().getResources()...
```

Because it turns out `ServiceTestCase` does not have a `getInstrumentation()` since it does not extend [`InstrumentationTestCase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html) method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *hack* works from my `ServiceTestCase` subclass:

```
Context context = getContext().createPackageContext(this.getClass().getPackage().getName(),
                   Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
context.getResources()...
```

Although a more standard way to this is welcome.

Comment: not working for me... Is this still working on KitKat?